# mysql query returning different results on two separate systems

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have this really simple query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `users` 
where from_unixtime(reg_date/1000) >= '2014-12-17'
```

My local mySQL server:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.3

The remote server:
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using re

Apart from being 32bit versus 64bit, they are the same.

Total records in both tables are the same - 257 rows.

Running the query on the server gives me a count of 202.

Running the query on my PC gives me a count of 203.

Same database, same table, same number of rows in the users table, actually exported from server, PC table truncated, and imported to PC.

Further, doing this on the PC:

```
select 
    year(from_unixtime(reg_date/1000)) as year, 
    month(from_unixtime(reg_date/1000)) as month,
    count(from_unixtime(reg_date/1000)) as the_count
from users
where from_unixtime(reg_date/1000) >= '2014-12-17'
group by 1,2
```

gives me:

```
year  month  the_count
2014   12    21
2015    1    87
2015    2    95
```

ie: total 203, but on the server, gives me:

```
year  month  the_count
2014   12    21
2015    1    90
2015    2    91
```

total: 202

I cannot for the life of me work out why this is happening...

I've read other posts but none of them have helped, as they were talking about joins and ID's being out of whack etc.

Query tool on PC: localhost/phpmyadmin

Query tool for server: mySQL Workbench on PC connecting to remote server with certificate etc.

OS on both server and PC:

Server: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

PC: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can track this down?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you check the locale of your db as well as the client? I looks little like a timezone impact.

Comment: @frian - thanks! I thought may have been it, but sadly, no. Running the "locale" command on both PC and server produce *exactly* the same output:

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_AU.UTF-8
LC_ALL=


The onlu difference being that PC had LANGUAGE=en, where server is blank.

Comment: @frian - after further checking, the timezone of the server is UTC. The timezone of the PC is AEST. I'll need to make some changes! :) Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I dont have a solution but I've got an idea how to track this down
Did you not notice that the_count matches for december 2014 but it doesnt match for either january OR febuary

I've only used sqlite3 but try changing the

```
    group by 1,2
```

to

```
    group by year,month
```

or maybe

```
    group by 2,1
```

Comment: I also thought that my help, but no:

group by year, month gives me:
`code`
2014 12  21
2015 1  181
2015 2      1